# Should acupuncture meridian questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

Here is example of the question:

- [Can wisdom tooth cause hip ache?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/230/can-wisdom-tooth-cause-hip-ache)

which relates to [The meridian system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_%28Chinese_medicine%29) ([meridian-system](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meridian-system)?) in Chinese medicine which is based on [kinesiology](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kinesiology). Which obviously is about health.

I've given the answer to show that kind of questions are answerable, but they need different approach.

Please share your thoughts if that kind of questions should be on topic or not.

Comment: Similar: [Should alternative medicine be on-topic?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/95/114)

Comment: Kinesiology is not chinese, it was founded in the US in 1964. And it has nothing to do with acupuncture

Comment: I think it's opposite, the meridian system has not much to do with [kinesiology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinesiology) which is not based on scientific evidences (but on [alternative medicine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_medicine)). Your question doesn't make sense in kinesiology, however it make sense only with meridian system which is related to kinesiology. If you're expecting answer in kinesiology (study of human movement), then your question doesn't have proper answer.

Comment: You said that _the meridiano system has not much to do with kinesiology_ and _meridian system which is related to kynesiology_. I don't get your point

Comment: @Garrett The other question is for me too broad and OP said it's rather about quality of the answers, than the whole 'alternative medicine' topic. This one deals with specific topic.